# didReceiveRemoteNotification not getting invoked

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am creating app in iOS/android. When a remote notification is received in the device, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` should get called. But it is not happening. My server side code for sending msg through APNS is as under:

```
$deviceToken = $obj_listener->ref_id;

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'blahblah';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/var/www/mobileapp/TestAppCK.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
                           'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                           $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp){
    $this->log->debug("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

$badge_count = $obj_listener->badge_count + 1;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(                  
                    //'alert' => 'Message received',
                    'sound' => 'default',
                    'badge' => $badge_count,
                    'msg_id' => $this->msg_id,
                    //'user_key' => $obj_listener->ref_id,
                    'email' => $obj_listener->to_email_id
                );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

My objective-c side code is as under:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{ 

    //UIWebView *NewWebView = NULL;
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification function");

    return;
}
```

I have checked for the device token in the server side code. It is correct for the device.
Why is the above function not getting called. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in you iPhone settings, if push notification is ON for your application

Comment: Also, Make sure you are using the correct provisioning profile (linked to the certificate which you would have used in the server code.)

Comment: it is not at all reaching the device.

Comment: Are you finding that it's not getting invoked at all, or only when the app is not running?
I'm getting it invoked if the app is in the foreground or background, but not if the app isn't running at the time of the notification.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't register for notifications at your app start, they will never be received.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Now, about your server side, I suggest you run your code in debug mode and see if Apple's gateway is being properly reached through SSL. A simple bad cert or lack of it can take you away days of work. Personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

If Application is not in background you should use following code

```
   //-------------- check notification when app is come to foreground after apllication get terminated ----------------//

UILocalNotification *localNotif =

[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (localNotif) {

    [self handleRemotNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]]; // private method


}
```